# Swift 4 | Referencing database file for SQLite queries "unable to open database file"

Tags: swift, database, sqlite

[To begin, here is an image of my current project file set-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uJM6.png)

I am using the following in this project:

```
import UIKit
import SQLite
import GRDB
```

When I execute the following code :

```
        {
        tagString = x
        let dbQueue = try! DatabaseQueue(path: "data.db" )
        try! dbQueue.inDatabase { db in
            let rows = try Row.fetchCursor(db, "SELECT * FROM quotes WHERE genre = ? AND LENGTH(quote) < 100",
                                           arguments: [tagString])
```

I get the following error "unable to open database file"  as well as the warning "could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. This may reduce the quality of type information available."

I have tried changing "data.db" to simlpy "data", but that does not work.

The only solution I have found is when I write the complete path from my computer AND run it on a simulated app. If I try to use the entire path (ex. /Users/myName/Desktop/AppName/data.db) on my phone, the program crashes ( I assume because that memory location does not exist on the phone)

**Question:** Is my calling of the database correct? If so, any ideas of why It might not be able to find it?

Thankyou.

Comment: What is the mysql tag for?

Comment: mysql tag removed

Answer (score 0):

You get the "unable to open database file" error because you don't specify a valid path to your database.

On iOS, application files must be created at a *valid path*. Valid paths include paths inside the application's Documents folder. For example:

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
let dbPath = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent("data.db")
let dbQueue = try DatabaseQueue(path: dbPath)
```

Please refer to the [File System Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) chapter of iOS documentation for more information.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, the SQLite file that I am implementing is pre, loaded with data, from the screenshot above, is that the correct place to store the data.db? Because with the code provided it cannot find any of the databases contents

Comment: Edit: Problem solved, Data.db had to be added as a target

Comment: Good. I recommend you have a look at this FAQ: [How do I open a database stored as a resource of my application?](https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/blob/master/README.md#how-do-i-open-a-database-stored-as-a-resource-of-my-application).